# RoboGuice dependency Injection in a Fargment

Tags: android, roboguice

i have been using RoboGuice dependency injection with a Activity and a Fragment Activity. But i cannot figure out how i can use it using a fragment as we dont call setContentview in the Fargment. Can anyone show me an example of how to use this ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/injectfragment) a post that describes the solution. Main steps are:

1. Extend `RoboFragment`.
2. Return a root `View` from `onCreateView()`.
3. Use `@InjectView` annotations the same way you do in `RoboActivity`.

Comment: Thanks i figred it out. The injected views are available in OnActivityCreated function of the Fragment.